# Failed to lookup view "error" in views directory using handlebars

Tags: javascript, express, handlebars.js

I am new with express and handlebars. I wanted to use handlebars as a template engine on my express.js app but then I keep on receiving this kind of error:[image]

which was get generated by this code

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('static-favicon'); 
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var exphbr   = require('express3-handlebars'); // "express3-handlebars"

var routes = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views/'));
//app.set('view engine', 'jade');
app.engine('handlebars', exphbr({defaultLayout: 'main'}));
app.set('view engine', 'handlebars');

app.use(favicon());
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded());
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', routes);
app.use('/users', users);

/// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    var err = new Error('Not Found');
    err.status = 404;
    next(err);
});

/// error handlers

// development error handler
// will print stacktrace
if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
    app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
        res.status(err.status || 500);
        res.render('error', {
            message: err.message,
            error: err
        });
    });
}

// production error handler
// no stacktraces leaked to user
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.render('error', {
        message: err.message,
        error: {}
    });
});


module.exports = app;
```

what else am I missing or am I doing it right? Please help, I have been stuck for 1 day.

Comment: Can you run `$ tree -L 3` in your app's root directory and put it here? We have no idea what's in your `./routes/index` or `./routes/users` files, or your `/views` directory.

Answer (score 13):

The issue is the following line

```
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views/'));
```

Express is looking for a file called `error.jade` in the folder `views`. If the file exists, possibly try removing the extra `/` from `views/`.

I just ran into a similar problem because I moved the `views` folder into another folder called `app_server` so the solution was to replace the line with

```
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, '/app_server/views'));
```

Comment: I was having the same issue, but I fixed it without looking at this answer. Came back to add one myself but saw yours.

Answer (score 11):

You should have a View within your application currently named error.jade. Because you set up your application to use Handlebars the view engine is attempting to look for error.handlebars.
You should put modify the file and that will do it.

Comment: Thanks. I thought the extension was `.hbs` so this was driving me mad all day trying to figure out.

Answer (score 3):

I had this issue when I upgraded the server. 
All I had to do is run this

```
npm update
```

Comment: Please include this as a comment, this is not an answer!

Comment: I am a newby. I coulnd't seem to add comment unless i have some 50 reputations. I will leave this is as an answer for now

Answer (score 2):

If the view engine is not set to jade/pug you have to use the extension right here:

```
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    res.locals.message = err.message;
    res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

    // render the error page
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.render('error.pug'); <<<<<HERE!
});
```